# What is $f(2)$ if $f'(x) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^x\right)$ and $f(0) = 1$?

Tags: calculus, integration

If $$f'(x) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^x\right)$$ and $f(0) = 1$ then $f(2) =?$

I'm currently studying for my calculus exam and came across this multiple choice question. I have tried to do $u$ substitution to get $f(x) + c$. And then to just plug in the values. I have been dwelling on this for half an hour now either I'm doing it right and getting the answer wrong I have the wrong approach. Would someone please be kind enough to show a step by step guide for questions like these in general ( so its useful for other people as well).

The choices are:

- A $-1.819$
- B $-0.843$
- C $-0.819 $
- D $0.157$
- E $1.157 $

Comment: That does not have an obvious integral so I suspect there is an error in transcription

Comment: @Henry: You are right I think as the OP used "x" for times and the independent variable. I think this should be $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^x\right)$. OP should correct.

Comment: @Jon: Even then, you need to use the sine integral, which is not suitable for multiple choice questions.

Comment: @Henry: You are right. Indeed, $\int dx\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^x\right)$. I put $y=e^x$ and so $\frac{dy}{y}=dx$ and so we are left with sine integral. Unless this is homework requiring some numerical evaluation.

Comment: Is $f(2)=1+ \int_0^2 \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}xe^x\right)$ among the choices?

Comment: @John: When you ask about a multiple choice question, you should supply the choices, since deciding between supplied alternatives is alternatives-dependent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response guys, the choices are as follows: 
A -1.819
B -0.843
C -0.819
D 0.157
E 1.157

And there is no additional x inside the sin bracket, it should say f′(x)=sin((π/2)e^x)

Comment: @John: Edit your question removing x from the sine argument and add choices.

Comment: Since the set of $x$ with $f'(x) < 0$, has total length $<1$, and $f'\ge -1$ there, the answer is positive.  That rules out three choices.  How close to zero can the answer be?  Not 0.157...  That leaves 1.157.

Comment: Hi @GEdgar, you're a professional mathematician, right? Unfortunately your argument seems a bit too succint for me... Could you elaborate on that please?  Eg. "total length < 1" is not clear to me at all... I believe it's something like "since $(e^x)'$ is strictly positive, ..." Moreover I don't see why 0.157 is too close to zero. BTW, here is [f'(x) plotted by Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=sin(pi%2F2*e%5Ex)+from+-0.5+to+2.5)

Comment: Let $$\int_{0}^{2} f'(x) dx = A$$ where $A =$ area under $f'(x)$ between $0 \le  x \le 2$. But $$\int_0^2 f'(x) dx  = f(2) - f(0).$$ So $$f(2) = A +1$$ Show that $A$ is positive for $0 \le x\le 2$, and the answer will be $1.157$. But I don't know how to show that!

Comment: @nodakai: That plot has $e^x$ in the denominator, unlike the current statement of the question.  Which is it?

Comment: @GEdgar: Oops, "*" disappeared somewhere while I copy&pasted the URL... [This is a corrected version](https://www.google.com/search?q=sin(%28pi%2F2%29e%5Ex)+from+-0.5+to+2.5)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a picture.

[image]

The function $f'$ is in red.  Consider another function $g$ with $g \le f'$, seen in green.  The points on the $x$-axis are 0.6, 1.4, 1.7.  The negative parts are $-1$, the positive parts are piecewise linear, with peaks where the curve is maximum, namely at $x=0$ and at $x=\log 5$.  If we compute
$1+\int_0^2 g(x)dx$ it is easy, two rectangles of known size, two triangles
of height 1 and known widths, plus the 1.  The answer is 0.35.  But this is smaller than the value $1+\int_0^2 f'(x)dx$.  The only choice bigger than 0.35 is, therefore, the answer.